# doRedis with strange socket connection error in Ubuntu Linux, R, and RStudio

Tags: r, ubuntu, redis, rstudio, r-doredis

I am trying to get doRedis R package working in my latest Ubuntu 10.0.4 environment with R 2.12.1. I tried download the latest 2.15.1 but it installs (with apt-get install...) this other version. Anyhow, when I run the following lines from doRedis.R (http://bigcomputing.com/doredis.R):

```
library('doRedis') #no issues here 
registerDoRedis(queue='jobs')
```

I get the error of:

```
registerDoRedis(queue='jobs')
Error in socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE, timeout = timeout) : 
  unused argument(s) (timeout = timeout)
```

I also have the Redis-server running waiting to accept connections with no problems. I could connect with Redis-cli client no problems. This is all local to the same system. 
This runs fine on my Windows 7 with no problems. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version Ubuntu has in its own repositories is quite old. You can add CRAN to your `sources.list` and get the latest version through that repository. Read the instructions at [this page](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/) for more information.

In regard to your real question, it seems that a call to `socketConnection` includes an input argument it does not support. Please check which version of the package you are running, is it the same as you run under Windows 7? In addition, please upgrade your version of R to 2.15 using the link above.

Comment: Thanks Paul but I am switching to CentOS to see what happens