# socket connection error in doredis on AWS EC2

Tags: r, parallel-processing, amazon-ec2, redis

I have set up an instance to use as a redis worker. All ports are open. When i issue

```
library("doRedis")
redisWorker(host="ZZZ-23-20-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com", queue="jobs")
```

i get the error

```
Error in socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE, timeout = timeout) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE, timeout = timeout) :
  ZZZ-23-20-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6379 cannot be opened
```

Any ideas what could be going on? I have also used the inernal EC2 IP (10.XXX.XXX.ZZZ) still get the same error. The server is up, running and `ping`able

I am running latest and greatest of R, doRedis,Ubuntu 12.04 all fully updated. This has been discussed before but no solution found. [doRedis with strange socket connection error in Ubuntu Linux, R, and RStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732368/doredis-with-strange-socket-connection-error-in-ubuntu-linux-r-and-rstudio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have had similar issues although with registerDoRedis() as you cannot set a timeout and I believe the problem is with the timeout value used in the function 'redisConnect'.

In R if you run fix(redisConnect) and you can see the default for timeout is as follows:

redisConnect <- function (host = "localhost", port = 6379, returnRef = FALSE, 
    timeout = 2147483647L)

It seems this huge timeout value is causing the issue.  To check change it on the line it is used from this:

```
con <- socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE, 
    timeout = timeout)
```

To this:

```
con <- socketConnection(host, port, open = "a+b", blocking = TRUE, 
    timeout = 30)
```

I find that works although as soon as you reload the package the change gets wiped.  I just found this today so will submit a bug to the developer.  I'm running R 2.15 on OSX by the way.

The function you are using *should* default to timeout 30, or you can try setting it on the function call to be sure rather than fix()'ing the underlying code.